# ¿Qué significa en python el error "KeyError: 'resources'"?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Ejecuto el programa y me aparece lo siguiente:

> KeyError: 'resources'

No consigo corregir el error, ¿alguien sabe qué significa?

Comment: Cuando python te da un error, también muestra lo que se llama el _stacktrace_, que es el volcado de qué función se estaba ejecutando (y qué línea) cuando se produjo el error, y qué función había llamado a ésta, etc, es decir, toda la pila de llamadas. Suele servirte para localizar si el error se ha generado desde una función escrita por tí, o desde otra a la que tú has llamado, quizás con parámetros incorrectos. O desde otra llamada desde un _framework_, quizás mal configurado, etc. Cuando preguntes por un error suele ser importante que muestres el stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Que en tu diccionario no existe la clave "resources".

Puede comprobarse con:

```
if "resources" in nombredeldiccionario:
    print("si está")
else:
    print("no está")
```